# Find the Jordan form of a 4 x 4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Find the Jordan Form of 
>   $$
> A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
> 0 & -16 & 0 & 0\\
> 1 & 8 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & -6\\
> 0 & 0 & 1 &5
> \end{array}\right]
> $$

First, write the matrix $A$ in block format as:
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
C_1 & 0\\
0 & C_2
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then we find the jordan form of $C_1$ and $C_2$
the eigenvalues of $C_1$ is $4$ with multiplicity $2$
the rank of $[C_1-4I]$ is $2$. hence, $C_1$ is diagnolizable and its jordan form $$J_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
4 & 0\\
0 & 4
\end{array}\right)
$$

the eigenvalues of $C_2$ are 2, 3. Hence $C_1$ is also diagonalizable and its jordan form $$J_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
3 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{array}\right)
$$

Finally, the jordan form of $A$ is $J_1\oplus J_2$

Is my solution correct?

Correction:
the rank of $[C_1-4I]$ is $1$. hence, the jordan form of $C_1$ $$J_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
4 & 1\\
0 & 4
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: Did you check to make sure there are actually two eigenvectors for the $C_1$?

Comment: I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation for $J_1$ is incorrect. If a matrix $C$ is diagonalisable and
all eigenvalues are the same, say $\lambda$, then we must have $C = \lambda I$.

Hence the Jordan form of $C_1$ cannot be diagonal. You can check that
$(C_1-4I) \neq 0$ and $(C_1-4I)^2 =0$, so the Jordan form of $C_1$ must be
$\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$.